# Google Cloud Functions warmup time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Do we know what the warmup/cold-start time is for a function on the new (still beta as of now) Google Cloud Functions? Or the timeout before it cools down again?

I've been trying Azure functions in the per-use mode, and it's been ridiculously bad - seemed inconsistent but I've seen 30 seconds, and it seems to be about 5 minutes of no-use before it cools down again.

I'm assuming Google's functions have the same issue, but I don't see even preliminary documentation on those time periods. The answer seems to be a "ping" every X minutes to keep it alive, but knowing what that X should be would make a difference in billing.

Comment: Just tried running a function and it had a cold start of about 500ms (beta). It does vary. It would be best if you tested it. Check out the related discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726870/firebase-cloud-functions-is-very-slow (firebase cloud functions uses the same tech)

Comment: Yep, so far my testing has shown just a negligible time, but at least with Azure, it was a little inconsistent, so I don't know if I can rely on that. If it's really just 500ms, or even a few seconds, I won't even worry about it. Thanks for the info on Firebase - I've seen documentation on that, but I didn't realize it was the same technology as the new cloud functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interesting [blog post](https://mikhail.io/2018/08/serverless-cold-start-war/) by Mikhail Shilkov, published in August 2018. At this time and based on his experiments, the minimum alive period observed for Google Cloud Functions (GCF) is *3 minutes*:

[image: Orange dots are warm and blue ones are cold]

As a consequence, using `X=2` should be enough to keep a single function warm and ready to serve a request. However, in that case, you should ask yourself whether it is still relevant to use a serverless solution such as GCF.

Comment: That's great information, thanks for the link. I wonder if something changed in the last year, or if I was was making some other mistake when I was seeing 30 second cold start times for Azure, since this data suggests that 3 seconds is about as bad as it gets.