# Flutter firebase messaging not receiving notifications

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on flutter notification using firebase messaging, I couldn't receive any notification. I sent the notification via server using `curl`, I could get it work in native android app (Android Studio) but not in flutter, any help would be appreciated. Below is my code.

**Flutter Notification code**

```
class FirebaseNotifications {
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging;

void setUpFirebase() {
_firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
}

void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  print(token);
});

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on resume $message');
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on launch $message');
  },
);
}

void iOS_Permission() {
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
    .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  print("Settings registered: $settings");
});
}
}
```

**Android Studio code**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);

    showNotification(remoteMessage);
}

private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
Map data = remoteMessage.getData();

String mesg = "New Notification";

Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 250, 250, 250});
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        builder.setContentTitle(data.get("title").toString())  // required
                //.setStyle(new 
 NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification()
.getBod 
y().toString()))
                .setStyle(new 
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mesg)) //custom data
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification_icon4) // 
required
              
                .setContentText(mesg) // custom data
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 250, 250, 250});
    }
}
```

**Server side code**

```
function sendtoUser($sendingTarget, $acc_name, $type_message, 
$type_of_transaction, $check_amount)
{

#API access key from Google API's Console
$API_ACCESS_KEY = "adazxc";
$registrationIds = $sendingTarget;
#prep the bundle

$fields = array(
    'to'        => $registrationIds,
    'data' => array(
        'title' => 'my title',
        'keyValue' => true,
        'receiverName' => $acc_name,
        'transType' => $type_of_transaction,
        'totalAmount' => $check_amount
    ),
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
#Send Reponse To FireBase Server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

**EDIT**

I somehow can receive notification but I noticed that my status bar not receiving the notification but it is printed in the console, however, when I close the app I can get the notification. So how do I able to receive notification in both situation?

Comment: @androidnewbielearnerI have the same problem, you saw solve?

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#receiving-messages):

> Depending on a **devices state**, incoming messages are handled differently.

| State | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Foreground | When the application is open, in view & in use. |
| Background | When the application is open, however in the background (minimised). This typically occurs when the user has pressed the "home" button on the device, has switched to another app via the app switcher or has the application open on a different tab (web). |
| Terminated | When the device is locked or the application is not running. The user can terminate an app by "swiping it away" via the app switcher UI on the device or closing a tab (web). |

And [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground--notification-messages):

> Notification messages which arrive whilst the application is in the **foreground** will not display a visible notification by default.

If your app is currently opened and in the foreground, the notification will not be shown even if it was sent successfully. You can confirm this by opening the snackbar in the notification event handler like below:

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message.notification?.title ?? '', maxLines: 2),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
});
```

If you're working with android and you want to display notification when in the foreground, you can use [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package as suggested from the FCM docs [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#android-configuration).

Answer (score 4):

`data` tag only for transferring more information to app, like where it has to redirect, image etc.. you have to add `notification` tag to display notification on status bar.

its seems you havent added notification content, please refer below sample message and configure same, it'll work

```
{
   "notification": {
      "body": "body",
      "title": "title"
   },
   "priority": "high",
   "data": {
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "id": "1",
      "status": "done",
      "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
   },
   "to": <fcm_token>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some checks (Version numbers may change):

- Add google-services.json (Download from firebase console) to
  android/app/

In android/build.gradle:

- Add google() to repositories
- Add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' to dependencies

In android/app/build.gradle:

- Add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0' to
  dependencies
- Add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end
- Have the applicationId the same like package_name in the
  google-services.jon

Comment: I somehow can receive notification but i noticed that my status bar not receiving the notification but it is printed in the console, however, when i close the app i can get the notification. So how do i able to receive notification in both situation?

Comment: Am experiencing the same issue,how did you solve it.

Comment: androidnewbielearner and kenn, in flutter, foregrounds notifications will not be displayed. Your App state must be either "Terminated" or "Suspended" to receive notifications. However, you must be receiving payload while in foreground. You can present that data as a local notification if required, or as an alert

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had an issue with receiving `onMessage` notifications today (didn't try `onResume` or `onLaunch`) when it was working fine yesterday. No errors in the Functions logs and tokens were all the same.

Try restarting your device -- this seems to be the most consistent way to fix this if your functions were previously working.

Also, if the messaging seems slow at first, this may be due to cold starting when you aren't using the functions for a while (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726870/firebase-cloud-functions-is-very-slow) for a bit more information).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the scenarios are already mentioned here. However, along with the checklist mentioned by [@Zerj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3887548/zerj), I would like to add one more point.

- Check if your project has environment flavors for dev, staging, prod etc. In that case, the `google-services.json` file would reside in the respective folders (`android/app/development`, etc) instead of at the `android/app` level.
- If the above method too gives some problems for you, you can hardcode the credentials in the flavor's `MainActivity` file using `FirebaseOptions` class. You can find the usage [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/8184cba2c40842a180f91dcfb4a216e721cc6ae6/firebaseoptions/app/src/main/java/devrel/firebase/google/com/firebaseoptions/MainActivity.java#L32-L42)

More info about flavors - https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Answer (score -2):

You may miss manual configuration for android (as well as ios if required), refer below link

http://myhexaville.com/2018/04/09/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

Comment: This link is broken