# Deploying Firebase Functions hit build quota (Build Create requests per minute)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase project with 55 Functions. I sometimes got a deployment error saying that I hit the quota limit for `Build Create requests per minute` (the quota right now is 60) with the simplest deployment command,

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

And the CLI suggested me to deploy the remaining again using a command like this,

```
firebase deploy --only functions:functionA,functions:functionB
```

As it is a per minute quota, I was expecting the CLI to workaround the quota seamlessly. But it's not.

I sent an email to Firebase Support and they advised me to always use only 75% of the quota at one time when trying to deploy functions, but I wonder how everyone workarounds this quota issue ?

I read about organizing functions in groups in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions) and deploy group-by-group, but I wonder if there is other solutions ?

Comment: Are you facing the problem using `--only functions` flag as well or you just do not want to use it? What is wrong with this group-by-group deploy?

Comment: @vitooh I'm just wondering if there is a better solution. I think I could split into two groups according to the business logics, but if I need to keep adding new features, there might be chances that I hit the quota again. So I was thinking if there is a solution that will deal with this issue in a better way.

Comment: Are you keeping all the functions in one file? Is it JS or TS?

Comment: @vitooh I split all the functions in separate files. It's JS now. I did something similar to this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726870/firebase-cloud-functions-is-very-slow.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @Michael. I'm running into the problem with only 44 functions and I'll really like to avoid having to worry about dependencies between two deploy commands.

Comment: I have the very same issue too. Do you have any update / new knowledge on this one?

Comment: @kezor I've just realized your comments. The way that I did is to deploy functions batch-by-batch, like a few to 10s of functions, so this issue seems not to be coming up. But I feel like it's kinda workaround instead of a fix. Still hoping there is a better solution tho.

Comment: @Hunor Like I wrote above, got a workaround instead of a fix :(

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that you can use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build). BTW not sure if you know, that all your Firebase projects and functions are available in GCP as well. You can change and deploy them directly in GCP Console ([direct link](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/)).

In Cloud Build there is functionality that lets you to [deploy to Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase) with convenient configuration file in `yaml` or `json`.

The configuration file contain steps of your deploy and you can setup a `timeout` between them ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout)). So, you can create those steps with `--only` flag with control of time and you can use it created file many times and just adjust it when you add new function.

I think this will help you to avoid hitting quota limits, and I suppose you can use other features of Cloud Build as well.